# Iframe not launching URL just by changing subdmain (not a X-Frame-Options issue)

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-route53

I set up a wildcard SSL certificate on *.clipr.co, from Amazon AWS.
But I have a subdomain (adyoulike) that could not be launched in a iframe.
Iframe provides no error in console, and this is NOT a X-Frame-Options issue.

Ex with two subdomains mysecurite & adyoulike. There is not a single line of code or server configuration that is mentioning one of these two, so the exact same code is running.
It looks like iframe does not even try to launch adyoulike.clipr.co.

```
<!-- Works -->
<iframe src="https://mysecurite.clipr.co" width="400" height="800></iframe>

<!-- Doesn't work -->
<iframe src="https://adyoulike.clipr.co" width="400" height="800"></iframe>
```

We are on AWS, using Route 53 for routing and Beanstalk to run our code. But I doubt this is a AWS issue. SSL certificate has been generated with AWS too.

Does anyone encoutered the same issue ?

**EDIT** : Miss the codepen link to show the evidence : 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJomay

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by "JS doesn't like being in a frame" ? As url could not even be launched on iframe, there is no javascript running on it. I don't see what I could provide more ? I put two iframes, one is calling mysecurite.clipr.co, the other is not even called. There is not a single line "adyoulike.clipr.co" I could see on dev console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the second iframe (which has "adyoulike", which starts with "ad", in the hostname) loads … but only after I disable my advert-blocking privacy filters.

Comment: That's it ! I would never have thought of that one. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just note that this is **not** specific to the presence of "ad". If I launch "adyoulik" or "adyoulikee", this works. It looks like ad blocker have a blacklist of whole words they block in iframe if they are located in any part of the domain name.

Answer (score -1):

This might be caused by the browsers "Same origin Policy" which only allows content from one domain to be loaded.

If you need cross origin content you need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the required domains

Comment: The Same Origin Policy will never prevent content loading from an `iframe src`

Comment: Like @Quentin said, iframe does not even load src so it can't access targeted page header. Furthermore headers are exactly the same between mysecurite.clipr.co, which works, and adyoulike.clipr.co, which doesn't.